# Pointing to a particular php file when users navigate to the root url

Tags: iis, iis-8

The internal web is accessed using the following url: `crm.willys.local`

However, this page yields an under construction error and needs to be redirected to `crm.willys.local/login.php`

Is there a way to load `/login.php` using `IIS` when users navigate to `crm.willys.local`??

I appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the default document to be login.php.

Here is a technet link for IIS7, which should be about the same as IIS8.

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753615(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Wow, that was easier than expected! Thanks for the help! :)